# How to put 'spinner' on top of button

Tags: android, xml

Is there a way I can make my spinner be put on top of my button? (There will be various things **on top** of my button and when you press the button everything thats on it including the button will disappear)(the button spans the width of the screen) Now it's my spinner under my button. I tried looking at different RelativeLayout settings but it didn't work. Here's the xml code below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:minHeight="170dp"
    tools:context=".create"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:background="@color/colorText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="95dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="312dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shadow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:background="@color/colorText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/droid_sans"
        android:text="@string/done_label"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="128dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/droid_sans"
        android:text="@string/aisle_label"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/droid_sans"
        android:text="@string/qty_label"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.973"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/droid_sans"
        android:text="@string/item_label"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit: I put my button and spinner into a frame layout, and when I tested it on my phone it works. However I tested it on a phone of a  bigger size (and a newer android version) and the spinner doesn't show up (probably hidden again?) No idea why it would work on one phone but not the other,

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="327dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.195"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view">




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttontest"
        android:layout_width="313dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shadow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.863"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="102dp" />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="344dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.237"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />




</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml__

Comment: Why would you want to put it on top of a button? That makes no sense. If you want to click the button the spinner will be in the way. If you are just doing it for the background of the button, you can change the background of the spinner. Maybe you are wording your question in a bad way.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained a bit better. The button is a button that spans the width of the screen and it'll have bits of information on the button as well including the spinner. You'll be able to hold down the button and delete the button which deletes everything else inside it.

Comment: use ReilativeLayout or LinearLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering:

I put my 'button' into a FrameLayout then put the elements I want 'ontop' of it, under it (as in the code under it) like so:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="357dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.195"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.016">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttontest"
            android:layout_width="393dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shadow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.863"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="102dp" />


    </FrameLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="184dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="184dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="qty"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.06"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
findViewById(R.id.spinner).bringToFront();
```

Comment: where do I call this

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
    android:minHeight="170dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"

            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Done"
                android:textSize="20sp"

                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" aisle_label"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" qty_label"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.973"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" item_label"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#a4a4a4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#a4a4a4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to sort something out - I created a 'FrameLayout' and put both my spinner & button in there.

Should do the job, unless I find an issue, in which I'll come back here,this should be solved. :) Thank you